# Parts of the whole: Which base begets the largest percentage of fractions expressible as a terminating decimal?

Tags: number-theory, optimization

Update: It appears the question I actually *meant* to ask was quite different. As Robert Israel explained in his answer I was calculating the wrong thing. After writing [some ugly code](http://js.do/caffeinatedlogic/48835) (may take a sec to load) I searched and stumbled upon the sequence of the *correct* number of "nice parts" of a number [does not seem to have a closed form](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C5%2C2%2C4%2C3%2C6%2C2%2C8&sort=&language=english&go=Search). From the data I collected it appears the percentage ("the new $N(n)$") appears to shrink to zero. I feel it is safe to say that using this, maybe bad, metric, that after base six, base twelve is the best followed by base thirty and ten.

I also noticed Robert Israel's name appearing on that OEIS page, no wonder :)

---

Original post:

I could not decide on an appropriate title. Edit if you'd like.

I ran a rudimentary simulation to see which types of numbers give the highest percentage of fractional parts which are expressible as a terminating decimal. I started this because I was curious about other bases. Base twelve is often touted to be better than ten, as it is only marginally larger but offers more divisors.I am trying to quantify this behavior as follows. 12 is "better" than 10 in the sense that

$$\dfrac{1}{12},\dfrac{2}{12},\dfrac{3}{12},\dfrac{4}{12},\dfrac{6}{12},\dfrac{8}{12},\dfrac{9}{12},\dfrac{10}{12},\dfrac{12}{12}$$

are all terminating decimals in base $12$. In base 10, $70\%$ of all possible fractions are terminating decimals, as opposed to $75\%$ for base 12.

The number of these "nice parts" of the whole makes calculation easier in that base. It might be obvious that the percentage of what I'm calling "nice parts" of a number $n$ are

$$N(n) = \dfrac{n+1-\phi(n)}{n}$$

where $\phi(n)$ counts the number of relatively prime positive integers less than $n$ (a.k.a., Euler's Totient Function). Obviously primes are the worst with a percentage of $N(p)=2/p$.

My question is

> Considering only $n> 6$, does $N(n)$ achieve a maximum?

It seems like the sequence is bounded by $0.8$. $N(12), N(30)$ and $N(60)$ are pretty high, all are/about $75\%$, as I would expect. The numbers $210$ and $2310$ surprised me, with $N(210)\approx 77.61\%$, $N(2310)\approx 79.26\%$.

See [HERE](http://js.do/caffeinatedlogic/48815) for a list of the first thousand. You can make it higher, it will just take longer.

Comment: $\frac{5}{12}$ and $\frac{7}{12}$ also terminate in base $12$. In fact, any fraction where the denominator has prime factors $2$ and $3$ (i.e. the prime factors that appear in $12$) and no other primes all terminate.

Comment: I should have been more careful, thank you

Comment: I think what was meant was $1/j$ terminates with $1 \le j \le n$.  So for $n=12$ it's $$\dfrac{1}{1}, \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{3}, \dfrac{1}{4}, \dfrac{1}{6}, \dfrac{1}{8}, \dfrac{1}{9}, \dfrac{1}{12}$$ but not $$\dfrac{1}{5}, \dfrac{1}{7}, \dfrac{1}{10}, \dfrac{1}{11}$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Then the ratio would still be correct, throwing in zero I think? Or would it be $(n-\phi(n))/n$?

Comment: In order for $1/k$ to be terminating in base $b$, you need **all** prime factors of $k$ to be prime factors of $b$, not just one.  So no, your ratio is not correct.

Comment: Why should "percentage of all fractions" be limited to fractions whose denominator is $n$ or less? How _should_ it be defined?

Comment: @DavidK I did not think my question through. My intent was (at least a bad try at) quantifying those bases which gave the best "by hand" calculation advantage

Comment: @David I'm not saying you _can't_ do something like this. Just maybe think about what you want "percentage of all fractions" to mean. You could weight each fraction $\frac jk$ with $1<k\leq m$ and $0<j<k$ equally, and take a limit as $m\to\infty$, or maybe you would like to say it is more likely you have to deal with $\frac23$ than $\frac{3}{5701}$ and so you count $\frac23$ as a larger "percentage" of the total (but you must decide how much larger).

Comment: @DavidK I translated my actual question badly, it would have been a lot better of me to just state it plainly. Here is what I mean to accomplish: In base ten it is simple to talk about halves and fifths (as well as sums of such). In base 12 it is easy to talk about twelfths, sixths, and quarters (and so thirds, halves,etc). The number of these parts make arithmetic easier. For example, in base ten, dividing by 5 is as easy as moving the decimal point and doubling. In base 12  we can divide by 3 and 4 and 6 the same way, multiplying by 4,3 or 2 respectively and then move the decimal

Comment: @DavidK So I was looking for a way to count the number of these nice parts and see if there was really such a "best" base to do arithmetic in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maximize $N(n)$, you want to minimize $\phi(n)/n$.  Note that this is a multiplicative function of $n$, and $\phi(p^k)/p^k = (p-1)/p$ for prime $p$ and positive integer $k$.  If $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ are the first $k$ primes, 
$$\dfrac{\phi(p_1 \ldots p_k)}{p_1\ldots p_k} = \prod_{i=1}^k \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p_i}\right)$$
and this is the best we can do with numbers $\le p_1 \ldots p_k$.  Since
$\displaystyle\sum_i \dfrac{1}{p_i} = \infty$, $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p_i}\right) = 0$, so as $k \to \infty$ the product goes to $0$ and $N(p_1 \ldots p_k) \to 1$.

EDIT: But your $N(n)$ is not what you really want. The  numbers $m$ for which  $1/m$ terminates in base $n$ are those where all the prime factors of $m$ divide $n$.

Comment: Thank you. But $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1)$, correct?

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo - corrected.

Comment: You have gotten my idea correctly in spite of my bad statement, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given a large enough base with a suitable distributiin of prime factors, we can come arbitrarily close to $100$% of decimals being terminating. What is the smallwst base for which we reach, let us say, $90$%?

We might first try square-free bases $2,2×3,2×3×5,...$ with the idea that eventually $\phi(N)/N$, the proportion of fractions that will give repeating representations, drops below $0.1$. To minimize this we use tge smallest prime factors, hence the primorial sequence noted above.

For $2$ we have $\phi(2)/2=1/2=0.5$, for $2×3$ it's $(1/2)(2/3)=1/3=0.333...$, then comes $(1/3)(4/5)=4/15=0.266..$ and so on. The net fraction of nonterminating decimals drops below $0.1$ when the product

$\phi(N)/N=(1/2)×(2/3)×(4/5)×(6/7)...$

where the denominators are consecutive primes and the numerators one less drops below $0.1$ when

$N=2×3×5×7×...×257\approx\color{blue}{1.6516×10^{103}}$

OK. Could we do better quth non-squarefree numbers? No -- the ratio $\phi(N)/N$ depend only on distinct prime factors. So the above result for achieving $90$% of representations terminating is minimal!